# Images not showing in pug template

Tags: node.js, express, pug, mern, template-engine

I have put the images folder inside the views folder and added the relative path to the images but the images are not loading on the html page. I have tried multiple options like putting the folder outside views, giving absolute path but nothing worked. Can anyone please take a look and help me figure out what the error is?
[Screenshot of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eatry.png)

I have tried many options but nothing worked.
[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99n4Y.png)

Comment: 1. Your code should be added as text. 2. How do you serve images?

Comment: I agree with @Konrad, it looks like the issue is when serving the images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static files are processed differently from other types of routes in an Express application. A Http path for static files such as `abc.com/img/bg.jpg` does not map to a file bg.jpg in the views folder. Where it maps to is specified by the `express.static` function. So, something like:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"));
```

will map the Http path `/` for static files to the folder `public` in your application's launch folder.

See [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname) for more information on this parameter.